# Pass class name as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing

I have been trying to pass a class name as a parameter to a function in C++. i have a parent class 'troop' which has 10 child classes. I was unable to pass the datatype through template and had to use a bunch of if else statements to create objects of:

```
                    if (troops[i].getName() == "knight") {
                        if (*mana - knight::manaPrice >= 0) {
                            ptrToList->push_back(std::shared_ptr<knight>(new knight(ptrwindow)));
                            *mana -= knight::manaPrice;
                        }
                    }
                    if (troops[i].getName() == "archer") {
                        if (*this->mana - archer::manaPrice >= 0) {
                            ptrToList->push_back(std::shared_ptr<archer>(new archer(ptrwindow)));
                            *this->mana -= archer::manaPrice;
                        }
                    }
                    if (troops[i].getName() == "wizard") {
                        if (*this->mana - wizard::manaPrice >= 0) {
                            ptrToList->push_back(std::shared_ptr<wizard>(new wizard(ptrwindow)));
                            *this->mana -= wizard::manaPrice;
                        }
                    }
                    if (troops[i].getName() == "troll") {
                        if (*this->mana - troll::manaPrice >= 0) {
                            ptrToList->push_back(std::shared_ptr<troll>(new troll(ptrwindow)));
                            *this->mana -= troll::manaPrice;
                        }
                    }
```

As you can see, this could quite easily be generalized if i could pass the class name as a parameter to a function instead.

Comment: Well, you can't do that, but you can also easily generalize this by using a table.

Comment: Note that what you've shown is, more or less, the beginnings of a [factory pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Factory).